# How to back up my.cnf file from /etc/mysql

Tags: my.cnf

I encountered same problem here https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server

I am trying to follow the answers but I am not sure how to back up my.cnf file in /etc/mysql. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but /etc/my.cnf is probably only user-readable, so you will have to use sudo to back it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak` This basically copies the file and renames it.